# Android toast italics

Tags: android, toast, italic

I would like to display a toast in Android.  I decided that it would look nice to put one of the words in italics.  Is it possible to italicize a specific word for a toast?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. You can create a custom View. See [this tutorial](http://www.androidpeople.com/android-custom-toast-tutorial).

Answer (score 0):

I see Toast class has `setView` method. You could try giving it a different view with what you need.